# Reset all points' mean tilt

Tags: bezier-curves

is there a way to reset the mean tilt for all selected points of a curve?
I can't seem to find a way (I wish there was a scale (<kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> option or similar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset curve tilt in *Edit Mode* by selecting the desired vertex and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> (or <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>M</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> > *Clear Tilt*).

Comment: thanks bro! also, how do I make keys appear here in the forum? like you just did with alt T

Comment: with <kbd>name of the key</kbd>